# which template lang is this `<?js`

Tags: javascript, templates

I need to find a syntax highlighter for this template language (used by jsdoc)

```
<?js var a = 'hello'?>
```

It seems to be impossible to search the web for an answer and while I was sure to have used 80% of all template-languages this is the first time I have to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using [Underscore templates](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/blob/fb2c36781f01d74c13f3e5eabe96763646c264c6/lib/jsdoc/template.js#L39) (more [here](http://underscorejs.org/#template)) with [custom delimiters](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/blob/fb2c36781f01d74c13f3e5eabe96763646c264c6/lib/jsdoc/template.js#L26-L31).

Comment: Thx a bunch. Do you know if there is any syntax highlighter for this?

Comment: @pixelass, try a PHP highlighter, as it uses the same delimiter

Comment: I doubt it, since the delimiters are custom, but you can perhaps take an existing Underscore highlighter and modify it.

Comment: Sadly this is a very bad design.  PHP highlighters add colors but definitely not correctly. Thx for the help so far but I guess it makes no sense to use this.

Comment: I decided to fork jsdoc and remove the custom delimiters. Works perfectly so far. I will try to swap the template engine entirely since underscore templates (as most xml templates) uses a horrible syntax.